# How to get number of option is answered/not answered using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In android phonegap application, I created 5 or more question with respective option (checkboxes) in `div` dynamically. Each question and respective option have same id. Now I want to know how many question are answered/how many questions are not answered  while clicking submit button.

please guide me. Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
for dynamic div: retrive value from local database
function list(results){
for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                                         $("#poll").append("<li id='"+i+"'>"+results.rows.item(i).ques+"</li>"+"<br/>" );
                                      var optiontypearray  = new Array();
                                      var  arr = results.rows.item(i).option;
                                      var optiontypearray=arr.split(" ");

                                      for(var j=0; j<optiontypearray.length; j++) {
                                       $("#poll").append("<input  id='"+i+"'  name='ckbox' value='"+optiontypearray[j]+"'  type='checkbox'/>"+optiontypearray[j]+"<br/>");
                                      }

                          }
}
for submit  button:get question with respective answer
function submit(){
$answers = $(':checked');
  var $questions=$('li');
 $answers.each(function(index,el) {
 var list1=$(this).attr("id");
 alert("list1:"+list1);
 var val=$('#'+list1).val();
   alert($questions.eq(list1).html() + ' : ' + $(el).val());
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="poll">
```

Comment: can you share some of your code to get an idea ?

Comment: thanks for your reply.how to get how many questions are answered and not answered.please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the html related to question and answer?

Comment: In html I only declared div, using that div id append  question and option.<div id="poll"></div>

Comment: Note that the id's of elements should be unique for all elements on the same page. If you have to give elements id's, you should give them ones that are not used by any other element you are going to have on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens when you click submit button.

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var questionsAnswered = questionsNotAnswered = 0
    var arrQuestions = new Array();
    $('li').removeAttr('style').each (function (i) {
        if ($(this).children('input:checked').length > 0) {
            var ans = '';
            $(this).children('input:checked').each(function () {
               ans+= $(this).val() + ', ';
            });
            arrQuestions[questionsAnswered] = new Array($(this).attr('id'), ans);
            questionsAnswered++;
        } else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'required' && $(this).children('input:checked').length == 0) {
            $(this).css({border : '1px solid red'});
            questionsNotAnswered++;     
            alert($(this).clone().children('span').remove().end().text());
        }
    });    
    $('div#finalResults').html("Questions Answered : " + questionsAnswered + "<br /> Questions Not Answered : " + questionsNotAnswered);
    });
    $.each (arrQuestions, function () {
        $('div#finalResults').append("<br /> Q: " + this[0] + " A: " + this[1]);
    });
```

Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/tmM76/9/
Please note that the code in list() function might change as per your existing code which you did not share ;-).

Comment: Thankyou verymuch.It works fine.I have one more doubt how to get question with corresponding answer for storing  into localdatabase

Comment: Hey priya, check out the updated jsfiddle url and do not forget to upvote the answer If you like it :-)

Comment: It works fine.how to single check and multiple check set for option of each question.(ie)some question -only one option enable at a time.some question-mutiple option enable at a time .how to set this dynamically.please guide me.thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have two question ,one question should have multiple answer.and another question should have only one answer.(ie) each question have four option,for 1st question only one option is enabled at a time.for 2nd question more than one option is enabled please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the new fiddle url. I've made some changes in `list()` function and the `results` array.

Comment: I have one more doubt.set value for some questions " required=true " (for eg:multipleans=true) and set value for some question "required=false"
required=true means must answer that question
required=false means optional
while clicking submit button check whether if the question contain the value required=true  answered/not if it is answered get id and option of that questions and also other questions(required=false)(if it is answered) 
for storing value into database otherwise in alert display please answered that question(required=true)
please help me.how to do that?
thanks in advance

Comment: @priya: you can check which `li` tag has required flag. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/tmM76/8/

Comment: If it is possible show that question  (required=true)in alert if it is not answer that question

Comment: @priya: Glad to help you. Would you mind voting up the answer please :-)

Comment: please tell me how to application in background using phonegap.kindly guide me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

u can do something like..

```
var qanswered;

for( j = 0; j < numberofQuestions; j++){
       qanswered = false;
       ques = questions[j];
          for( k = 0; k < ques.choices.length; k++){
                btn = $('.ui-page-active input#'+k); // k is your choice id whatever way u define it
                      if(btn[0].checked){
                             qanswered = true;
                        }
          }
       if(!qanswered){
            //this question is not answered, do something
       }

}
```

btn gets the jquery object of the inputs one by one, of the ques

Comment: thanks for your reply.In your code please explain these {qusetion[j],ques.questionid,btn=$(),btn[0]}.I did not understand.please guide me.thanks in advance

Comment: btn is the jquery object of the inputs pf the question. one by one it sees the options of a particular question and sees if an input is checked(answered)

Comment: I have put this code,In logcat error:  btn[0] is undefined  ,how to solve this

Comment: dont go straight to android :P
first write the js code, and test it in a normal browser. debug using web inspector/firebug and then put that in android. u cant debug js in android

Comment: use fiddler/charles to debug local html js, in browser